# Fetch files from directory in created order?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Right now i have written this logic ..

```
  def get_file_names
    @files = []
    Find.find("#{BACKUP_FILE_DIR}") do |path|
      file_stat = File.stat path
      @files << {
        :name => File.basename(path,".*"),
        :mtime => file_stat.mtime,
        :path => path
      }
    end
    @files.delete_at(0)
    @files = @files.sort_by { |file| file[:mtime] }
    @file_names = []
    @files.each do |f|
      @file_names << [f[:name],f[:path]]
    end
  end
```

How could I improve this method?

Comment: See this question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/4739967/570156

Comment: Getting only folder name .. Not file names inside the folders.. >> files_sorted_by_time = Dir['/db_backups'].sort_by{ |f| File.ctime(f) }
=> ["/db_backups"]

Comment: The title says creation time, but that isn't available on Linux and Mac OS, and Ruby doesn't support it at all. Neither `ctime` or `mtime` is the creation time, they're variations of the modification times of the file.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use the "ctime" in File::Stat instead of the mtime

```
mtime : time last modified
ctime : time created
```

try this:

```
# recursively collect file names based on ctime:
#
def get_file_names( dir )
  Dir.chdir(dir)
  Dir.entries(dir).each do |f|
   # next if f == '.'
   # next if f == '..'
    next if f =~ /^\./    # ignore dot-files and dot-directories                                    

    full_filename = File.join( Dir.pwd , f)

    if File.directory?( full_filename )
      get_file_names( full_filename )
    else
      stat = File::Stat.new( full_filename )
      @files_by_ctime[stat.ctime] ||= []
      @files_by_ctime[stat.ctime] << full_filename
    end
  end
  Dir.chdir('..')
end ; 1

@files_by_ctime = {}

get_file_names('/tmp')

@files_by_ctime.keys.sort.each do |ctime|
  puts "Created: #{ctime} : #{@files_by_ctime[ctime].inspect}"
end ; 1
```