# How to list files that was modified last from a directory using ruby

Tags: ruby, list, file, time

```
# List the file that was updated the last
lst_fl = Dir.glob("/home/developer/myFiles/*")
files_updated_last = Dir["/home/developer/myFiles/*"]

Dir.glob(File.join("/home/developer/myFiles/", '*.rb')).each do |lst_fl|
files_updated_last.sort_by{|lst_fl| File.mtime(lst_fl)}
end
puts files_updated_last
```

Above is my ruby code. i want to list the files in a sorted way depending on their last modified time. please help how to achieve this ? With this code i m simply getting list of files but not in an ordered way of last modified time.

I want file list as per last modified time

Comment: Possible dup: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4739967/how-to-order-files-by-last-modified-time-in-ruby